# Exporting evince annotations

Tags: pdf, evince

Is there a way to export annotations made to a PDF using evince?

See, I have a fairly lengthy documents I commented on but I now need to share it with someone else.  Although the other person also uses Ubuntu, his evince version is relatively old (3.10.3) and does not seem to be compatible with my version of evince (3.18.2).

Although it would be great to solve this problem for this specific instance (again someone else also using evince) the problem is bigger than this as exporting the comments for other PDF viewers (acrobat for one) is also desirable.

Comment: Annotations somehow could be viewed in Firefox's embeded pdf viewer when hovered with mouse; yet still could not be viewed as it looks in evince.